# how to fix "no function to return from, jumping to top level" in R?

Tags: r, function

When i run below function it returns an error of "no function to return from, jumping to top level"

I dont seem to be able to find the error as the function seems to be properly structured.

All parameters are defined except maturity that changes, based on TTM which is a list of values.

Would you be able to help me understand the error message?

```
Condor_strategy <- function (TTM) {

    result = c()
        for (i in 1:length(TTM)){

        maturity = TTM[i]

        a = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K2,spot, stdv, Rf, 0, 0, 1, 10000, maturity * 365)
        b = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity,K4, spot, stdv, Rf, 0, 1, 1, 10000, maturity * 365)
        c = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K1,spot, stdv, Rf, 0, 1, 1, 10000, maturity * 365)
        d = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K3, spot stdv, Rf, 0, 1, 1, 10000, maturity * 365)

        result = append(result, a-b-c-d)

        }
    return(result)
}


> dput(head(TTM))
c(0.004, 0.008, 0.012, 0.016, 0.02, 0.024)


Error in append(result, a - b - c - d) : object 'a' not found
>         
>         }
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
>     return(result)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

Comment: 1) How is the function called? 2) Please start the scripts with `library(pkgname)` to load the packages used. 3) Can you post a data example? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(TTM))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas 1 ) function is called Condor_strategy 2) library is produced by me, its not publicatly available 3) > MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K1, spot, stdv, Rf, divr, 0, 0, 10000, 126)
[1] 0.2204701

my point here, is that i dont seem to be able to get the R function structure correct.

Comment: At the moment that code has a syntactic error.There's a missing comma between "spot stdv,"

Comment: @42- you are totally right! that is the reason, thank you so much!

Comment: If you had started from a clean session, and pasted this code into the console, the error would have been different. I got: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        cc = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K1,spot, stdv, Rf, 0, 1, 1, 10000, maturity * 365)
        d = MCAsianOptionPricer(maturity, K3, spot stdv"` and the the best way to deal with that error if to look carefully at the exact spot where the R parser was unable to proceed. It's offen a missing comma in my experience. I added this comment because the error you offered were not clearly related to the actual error.